# Python: How to compare two binary files?

Tags: python, debugging, hex, diff, instrumentation

In python I need to print a diff of two binary files. I was looking at `difflib.Differ` which does a lot.

However differ assumes lines of text and so the output does not list the byte index and the hex value difference.

What I need is output that has what byte is different, how the byte is different, the actual hex values of the two bytes.

**In Python, how do you compare two binary files (output: the byte diff index, the hex values of the two bytes)?**

I was doing something like:

```
# /usr/bin/env python2
import difflib
x = open('/path/to/file1', 'r').read()
y = open('/path/to/file2', 'r').read()
print '\n'.join(difflib.Differ().compare(x, y))
```

But this doesn't output the byte index where the difference is. And it doesn't print the hex values.

Comment: i can also just not use `difflib`. but i feel like there should be an elegant solution that uses `difflib`.

Comment: i just read the man page `man 1 cmp` and saw "compare two files byte by byte... --verbose output byte numbers and differing byte values"... i have a sneaking suspicion that just calling the cmp command from python will be the most elegant solution.

Comment: `cmp` also covers all the edge cases (for example one file is larger than the other, etc).

Answer (score 0):

When difflib compares it puts every char into an array with a + or - in front of it. Below compares x and y and then we look at the output:

```
d = difflib.Differ()
e = d.compare(x,y)        #set the compare output to a variable
for i in range(0,len(e)):
    if i.startswith("-"):         #if that char start with "-" is not a match
        print(i + "index is different")
```

The chars will start with a "-" that don't match. "+" Indicates they are matching.

Answer (score -2):

The shell command `cmp` already does exactly what I need/want. Reinventing that functionality in Python would be more effort/code/time... so I just called the command from Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import commands
import numpy as np
def run_cmp(filename1, filename2):
    cmd = 'cmp --verbose %s %s'%(filename1, filename2)
    status, output = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd) # python3 deprecated `commands` module FYI
    status = status if status < 255 else status%255
    if status > 1:
        raise RuntimeError('cmp returned with error (exitcode=%s, '
                'cmd=\"%s\", output=\n\"%s\n\")'%(status, cmd, output))
    elif status == 1:
        is_different = True
    elif status == 0:
        is_different = False
    else:
        raise RuntimeError('invalid exitcode detected')
    return is_different, output
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create two binary files with different values
    # file 1
    tmp1 = np.arange(10, dtype=np.uint8)
    tmp1.tofile('tmp1')
    # file 2
    tmp2 = np.arange(10, dtype=np.uint8)
    tmp2[5] = 0xFF
    tmp2.tofile('tmp2')
    # compare using the shell command 'cmp'
    is_different, output = run_cmp(filename1='tmp1', filename2='tmp2')
    print 'is_different=%s, output=\n\"\n%s\n\"'%(is_different, output)
```

Comment: On my system, `cmp` seems to only return the first mismatching byte and I don't see any manpage options to change that. Given that I'm trying to distill a big pile of attempted ROM dumps into a list of which bits have gone bad, that disqualifies it.